# Transferring special characters using xmlhttprequest

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest, codepages

I use xmlhttprequest in a javascript on my webpage to retrieve detail info from a database. 
With the xmlhttprequest I load a classic ASP snippet that reads data from the database and displays the info in a CSS-window.
The info contains special characters like [á,à,æøå].
In order to display these characters correctly I've found out that I need to put a

```
session.codepage=65001
```

in my ASP code snippet and that works fine.

However if I now save the data from the web form back to the server and then retrieve them again, the special characters are totally messed up.

Anyone has a good work around? Changing the database (MS SQL) setup is not an option.

Late addition: I have now narrowed the problem to Internet Explorer.

Addition 2 (7/7-13): In order to fix the IE problem, I had to cut it out of cardboard adding the following line to the javascript part, that handles the xmlhttprequest:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Now it runs fine. Later though, I would like to find out if all of these measures:

```
<%@Language=VBScript CodePage = 65001%>
<%
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID     = 1030 
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

really are necessary to make it run smoothly.

Comment: please show your insert code. Is the datatype in db `nvarchar` ?

Comment: Yes, I use NVARCHAR and now that I have done some further investigation and done all the right things as suggested in topic Stackoverflow.com/questions/12082867/classic-asp-character-encoding it turns out that the problem lies within IE. Special characters can now be saved and displayed properly in FF, but they display as ??? in IE.